# Application function call tracing

Tags: windows, visual-studio

I have compiled the source code of a project. I have all the pdb files needed for debugging. Now a profiler will tell me the percentage of time an application spends in some function. Is there some utility tool which can track all the application calls that an application makes during its execution. I want an output like strace but for application functions. Something like function A was called at time T with return value x...